# Cannot access numpy in cmd

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have Anaconda3 installed with Python3.7.1 in *C:\Anaconda3*. I have set following as my environment variables: *C:\Anaconda3*; *C:\Anaconda3\Scripts*; *C:\Anaconda3\python.exe*; *C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages*.

On Windows10, cmd recognises python and runs simple programs but throws ImportError when I try to access numpy. Numpy shows as installed in Anaconda GUI and I can access it through conda Command Prompt.

I need help to run my programs from cmd.

Edit: pip install recognises numpy as -

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)`
```

Comment: Try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300128/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-using-anaconda-from-the-command-line. It worked well for me.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by 'access'?  Are you doing `import numpy` in a Python script and interactive session?

Comment: Yes, 'access' means calling import numpy in a script.

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda 5.3.0 the numpy version accesses libraries that are on the system PATH set by conda when you use start the Anaconda Prompt or when you run:

```
conda activate base
```

from the CMD prompt.  This sets a handleful of environmental variables, but the important one is what conda adds to PATH.  There are a handleful of ways around this.  One is you can simply use the Anaconda Prompt to run your script, or you can run the above command before running your Python code.

Alternatively, you can also add a batch file to your Anaconda installation that activates the activates the environment and then passes any additional arguments to python.

Here is the content of the batch file

```
# file name:
# C:\Anaconda3\python.bat
call C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat base
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe %*
```

Now you can call you script by activating the base environment first and then firing the script via:

```
python.bat myscript.py
```

Comment: My version of conda is 4.5.12; there seems to be an error with conda activate command